# Cannot find class type name "Normalized"- Processing

Tags: arduino, processing

I'm having a dilemma with this code and have no clue what to do. I'm pretty new to processing. This is a project from this link...

http://blog.makezine.com/2012/08/10/build-a-touchless-3d-tracking-interface-with-everyday-materials/

any help is massively appreciated... Thanks in advance

```
import processing.serial.*;
import processing.opengl.*;

Serial serial;
int serialPort = 1;

int sen = 3; // sensors
int div = 3; // board sub divisions

Normalize n[] = new Normalize[sen];
MomentumAverage cama[] = new MomentumAverage[sen];
MomentumAverage axyz[] = new MomentumAverage[sen];
float[] nxyz = new float[sen];
int[] ixyz = new int[sen];

float w = 256; // board size
boolean[] flip = {
  false, true, false};

int player = 0;
boolean moves[][][][];

PFont font;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600, P3D);
  frameRate(25);

  font = loadFont("TrebuchetMS-Italic-20.vlw");
  textFont(font);
  textMode(SCREEN);

  println(Serial.list());
  serial = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[serialPort], 115200);

  for(int i = 0; i < sen; i++) {
    n[i] = new Normalize();
    cama[i] = new MomentumAverage(.01);
    axyz[i] = new MomentumAverage(.15);
  }

  reset();
}

void draw() {
  updateSerial();
  drawBoard();
}

void updateSerial() {
  String cur = serial.readStringUntil('\n');
  if(cur != null) {
    String[] parts = split(cur, " ");
    if(parts.length == sensors) {
      float[] xyz = new float[sen];
      for(int i = 0; i < sen; i++)
        xyz[i] = float(parts[i]);

      if(mousePressed && mouseButton == LEFT)
        for(int i = 0; i < sen; i++)
          n[i].note(xyz[i]);

      nxyz = new float[sen];
      for(int i = 0; i < sen; i++) {
        float raw = n[i].choose(xyz[i]);
        nxyz[i] = flip[i] ? 1 - raw : raw;
        cama[i].note(nxyz[i]);
        axyz[i].note(nxyz[i]);
        ixyz[i] = getPosition(axyz[i].avg);
      }
    }
  }
}

float cutoff = .2;
int getPosition(float x) {
  if(div == 3) {
    if(x < cutoff)
      return 0;
    if(x < 1 - cutoff)
      return 1;
    else
      return 2;
  } 
  else {
    return x == 1 ? div - 1 : (int) x * div;
  }
}

void drawBoard() {
  background(255);

  float h = w / 2;
  camera(
    h + (cama[0].avg - cama[2].avg) * h,
    h + (cama[1].avg - 1) * height / 2,
    w * 2,
    h, h, h,
    0, 1, 0);

  pushMatrix();
  noStroke();
  fill(0, 40);
  translate(w/2, w/2, w/2);
  rotateY(-HALF_PI/2);
  box(w);
  popMatrix();

  float sw = w / div;
  translate(h, sw / 2, 0);
  rotateY(-HALF_PI/2);

  pushMatrix();
  float sd = sw * (div - 1);
  translate(
    axyz[0].avg * sd,
    axyz[1].avg * sd,
    axyz[2].avg * sd);
  fill(255, 160, 0);
  noStroke();
  sphere(18);
  popMatrix();

  for(int z = 0; z < div; z++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < div; y++) {
      for(int x = 0; x < div; x++) {
        pushMatrix();
        translate(x * sw, y * sw, z * sw);

        noStroke();
        if(moves[0][x][y][z])
          fill(255, 0, 0, 200);
        else if(moves[1][x][y][z])
          fill(0, 0, 255, 200);
        else if(
        x == ixyz[0] &&
          y == ixyz[1] &&
          z == ixyz[2])
          if(player == 0)
            fill(255, 0, 0, 200);
          else
            fill(0, 0, 255, 200);
        else
          fill(0, 100);
        box(sw / 3);

        popMatrix();
      }
    }
  }

  fill(0);
  if(mousePressed && mouseButton == LEFT)
    msg("defining boundaries");
}

void keyPressed() {
  if(key == TAB) {
    moves[player][ixyz[0]][ixyz[1]][ixyz[2]] = true;
    player = player == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  if(mouseButton == RIGHT)
    reset();
}

void reset() {
  moves = new boolean[2][div][div][div];
  for(int i = 0; i < sen; i++) {
    n[i].reset();
    cama[i].reset();
    axyz[i].reset();
  }
}

void msg(String msg) {
  text(msg, 10, height - 10);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a class, in fact, more than one. Go back to the [github](https://github.com/Make-Magazine/3DInterface/tree/master/TicTacToe3D) and download, or copy and paste, all three codes, placing each one in a new tab named same name of the class (well this is not required, but is a good practice). The TicTacToe3D.pde is the main code. To make a new tab choose "new tab" from the arrow menu in Processing IDE (just below the standard button at the right). The code should run. WIll need an Arduino though to really get it working.